# Allow line break in BibLaTeX output

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, line-breaking

I have an BibLaTeX entry which causes in `\printbibliography` command a overful hbox. How can I tell BibLaTex that a line break is allowed without a minus symbol?

In my case I have a text like `ABC.learning`. I want to allow BibLaTex to break the line after the dot.

Comment: Add `\discretionary{}{}{}` after the period.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My solution is to add a 0pt hspace.

```
ABC.\hspace{0pt}learning
```