# Line break in title in biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I have some bibliography entries with points in the title field like "org.apache.lucene.analysis" or "java.util.Date". As there is no linebreak after ".", the text runs over the page margin in some cases. Is there a way to change this behaviour?

Comment: I'd hazard the guess that those words don't get good hyphenation points from LaTeX's algorithm. You probably need to indicate possible line breaks with`\-` manually.

Comment: See also [Allow line break in BibLaTeX output](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40951/35864), where even the use case is the same.